# Reactjs: How to update value in state array with react hooks?

Tags: reactjs

this is my state of array.

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([
   {
     "id": 1,
     "barcode": "8851907264888",
     "qty" : 1
   }, 
   {
     "id": 2,
     "barcode": "8857124022072",
     "qty": 1
   }
]);
```

if I want to update `qty` to `2` in `array[0]` , what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can copy the arr to a new array and update the qty field and setArr with new array.

```
 let newArr = [...arr]
  newArr[0].qty=2;
  setArr(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can update your single object value. [Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wright-e9gux?file=/src/App.js:51-480)

```
export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = React.useState([
   {
     "id": 1,
     "barcode": "8851907264888",
     "qty" : 1
   }, 
   {
     "id": 2,
     "barcode": "8857124022072",
     "qty": 1
   }
]);
const handleUpdate=()=>{
  arr[0].qty=2;
  setArr({...arr})
}
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <h3>{JSON.stringify(arr[0])}</h3>
     <button onClick={handleUpdate}>Update</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```